# Convet texinfo to org

Tags: org-mode

I tried to convert a texinfo file to an org file:

```
pandoc --wrap=none calendar.texi  -o calendar.org
```

Unfortunately, it outputs a messy text.

Since texinfo act as emacs default markup language, while org act the king extension.

Is there an easy solution to perform such a conversion?

Comment: Not a solution, but why don't you use emacs buitin functionality of reading `info` documentation (`M-x info`)? This is comfortable enough to look up documentation. (Note: `info` documentation is created out of `texi` files)

Comment: It comes with the defects of inable to make notes. @jue

Comment: AFAIK, you can go the other way only: org-mode can convert org to texinfo (nowadays, the org manual itself is an org mode file and is converted to texinfo in order to build the info-browsable documentation), but I don't know of anything that would convert texinfo to org.

Comment: again not a solution, but you could circumvent this by writing notes in an org-file and from there creating links to info documentation. This is supported by org-mode